# How to let subcomponent know that inputs changed?

Tags: angular

I use Angular 10 and I have a ParentComponent, and a ChildComponent. The ChildComponent has an `@Input` to members of the parent.

Due to a promise, it takes a while until the members of the parent are generated. I use `this.cd.detectChanges()` later to inform the child to redraw.

How can I now update some members of my child component? Is there an observer or subscriber pattern to these changes? What would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `detectChanges`, use the `async` pipe to provide the result of the Promise:

```html
<app-my-child-component [myInput]="myPromise$ | async">
```

If your Promise returns an array of images you wish to display, I would advise the following:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="myPromise$ | async as images">
  <img *ngFor="let image of images" [src]="image"> 
</ng-container>
```

The `ng-container` gives you a hook for the `*ngIf` directive and allows you to create the `images` alias (an Angular best practice for dealing with Observables and Promises). You then use `*ngFor` to loop through the aliased returned array to display your images.

Comment: Thank you! That's already very helpful. In my case the Input is an array of images I want to display in the child component. So I would need to connect that with `<img [src]="?? | async?`>`. Do you have a tip for me?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `ngOnChanges` life cycle method to detect change whenever an `@Input` binding value changes.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.input_var.currentValue != changes.input_var.previousValue) {
      /* write your code here */
    } 
  }
```